# Parametarized links in HAL json

Tags: json, api, rest, hal-json

Assuming I have an endpoint `GET /api/foos/{id}` which has optional parameters:  includes, query, type should I create a link for each of the 'usecases' or can I include it as a single link?

Should it look more like this:

```
"_links":{
   "self": { "href": "/api/foos/1" },
   "includes": { "href": "/api/foos/1{?includes}", "templated": true },
   "query": { "href": "/api/foos/1{?query}", "templated": true },
   "type": { "href": "/api/foos/1{?type}", "templated": true },
}
```

Or maybe like this:

```
"_links":{
   "self": { "href": "/api/foos/1" },
   "query": { "href": "/api/foos/1{?includes}{?query}{?type}", "templated": true },
}
```

What if I also have paging related links, like next, prev etc. Should I include these templates for them, too? For example:

```
"next": { "href": "/api/foos?page=2{?includes}", "templated": true }
```

Comment: Your next link definitely should not be templated. If you are going to the next page in a collection, the next link should specifically refer to the next page for the current results. If that includes query parameters, these should probably be hardcoded with their actual values.

Comment: Also the correct syntax is `{?includes,query,type}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RFC6570, Section 3.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.1) (which is the foundation for URL templating) you can add multiple parameters and parameter without a value will be ignored:

> A variable that is undefined (Section 2.3) has no value and is ignored by the expansion process.

That means for your example that you can use following HAL response:

```json
"_links":{
   "self": { "href": "/api/foos/1" },
   "query": { "href": "/api/foos/1{?includes,query,type}", "templated": true },
}
```

And it should work for your paging example as well.

Comment: `{?includes,query,type}` is the correct syntax